# Google App Engine, parsedatetime and TimeZones

Tags: django, google-app-engine, timezone

I'm working on a Google App Engine / Django app and I encountered the following problem:
In my html I have an input for time. The input is free text - the user types "in 1 hour" or "tomorrow at 11am". The text is then sent to the server in AJAX, which parses it using this python library: http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/. Once parsed, the server returns an epoch timestamp of the time. 
Here is the problem - Google App Engine always runs on UTC. Therefore, lets say that the local time is now 11am and the UTC time is 2am. When I send "now" to the server it will return "2am", which is good because I want the date to be received in UTC time. When I send "in 1 hour" the server will return "3am" which is good, again. However, when I send "at noon" the server will return "12pm" because it thinks that I'm talking about noon UTC - but really I need it to return 3am, which is noon for the request sender.. I can pass on the TZ of the browser that sends the request, but that wont really help me - the parsedatetime library wont take a timezone argument (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there a walk around this? Maybe setting the environments TZ somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Please either select an answer or provide more details

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is add the difference using a timedelta object (http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

The offset

here's some (very rough) code to give you the idea:

```
import parsedatetime
import datetime

my_users_timezone = whatever #replace this with a string that will make sense in the offsets dictionary

utc_timezone_offsets_in_hours = {
   'utc' : 0,
   'pacific' : -8,
   # etc
}

parsed_time = parsedatetime.whatever(input_string)
offset_hours = utc_utc_timezone_offsets_in_hours[my_users_timezone]
final_time = parsed_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset_hours)
return final_time
```

Comment: dorkitude has the proper approach and should be selected as answering the question

Answer (score 0):

`parsedatetime`'s parse routine expects a `timetuple()` as the `sourceTime` parameter and should carry over any timezone information you include in it as I don't recall writing any code that overrode it.  If it doesn't then it's a bug and let me know.

You can use code like how the answer above suggested for now to add the TZ offset after the `parse()` routine returns what it has determined the datetime to be:

```
import parsedatetime as pdt

cal = pdt.Calendar()

start  = datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()

parsed, flag = cal.parse('in 1 hr', start)
```

then you can take the `timetuple` value of `parsed` and use `timedelta` to add your offset hours